# Camera setParameters failed : FATAL EXCEPTION

Tags: android, android-camera

I am trying to capture an image by using the Camera API.

Everything works well until I set the camera focus mode parameter with **Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_EDOF**.
Before setting focus mode I check if **PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA_AUTOFOCUS** is available or not.

Below is my code: My test environment in `LG Optimus Net Android 2.3.4 with autoFocus feature`

```
    if (mContext.getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(
            PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA_AUTOFOCUS))
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH) {
            params.setFocusMode(Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_CONTINUOUS_PICTURE);
        } else {
            // Below parameter not working
            params.setFocusMode(Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_EDOF);
            // If i set FOCUS_MODE_AUTO then it will work fine but image
            // quality is little bit downgraded compare to default camera
            // application
            // params.setFocusMode(Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_AUTO);
        }
```

Any hint will be helpful

Comment: Have you checked whether ``FOCUS_MODE_EDOF`` is supported by calling ``Parameters.getSupportedFocusModes()``?

Comment: @harism i check supportedFocusModes and it solve my problem, edof is not in list, strangely i get continuous-camera so is continuous-camera & continuous-picture mode are same, i didn't found continuous-camera in http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.Parameters.html